# How can I position a div underneath a fixed div with variable height?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a header div with fixed position that increases in height when the text inside of it wraps.  The text is different depending on which unit page you are on, so I can't use a media query to fix the position of the lower div because the width at which the text wraps changes every time.  Is it possible to position the lower div relative to the fixed upper div using just CSS and/or Angular?